# Error with bourbon/neat gems in rails 4 scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, bourbon, neat

Inside my `application.css.scss` i have the following code

```
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'neat';
@import 'neat-helpers';

div.container {
  @include outer-container;
}
```

however upon starting my rails app (i am using the better-errors gem) i get the following screen

[image: rails-4-screengrab]

removing both the `@imports` works but then i get no css

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the 'environment' method in one of those files. Try removing the line with that call or post it in the comments.

Comment: the 'enviroment' call has to be coming from the gem because after removing the `@import bourbon` and `@import neat` this error goes away

Comment: Try removing:@charset 'utf-8';

/*
*= require zurb--bower-foundation';
*= require bourbon';
*= require neat';
*/

Comment: also remember to restart your server after bundle install

Comment: removing the charset and requires did nothing

Comment: after restarting, try removing them one at a time to isolate the source of the error